# Violation of Newton's 3rd law

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, relativity

I'm just expressing my guess. 
Let two particles A and B  experiences forces $F_1$ and  -$F_2$ between them and let guess also there are two observer, one is stationary and other is moving with constant speed. Now my measurement  time for the collision will not same for the moving observer.

So If I am stationary, the  moving observer may say that my measurement is wrong that means Newtons third law is violated? Is it right?

Comment: Are you saying that the times of collision will be different? But why? Remember, in Newton's theory time is absolute.

Comment: Consider special  relativity,  your time and mine are not same. and this condition is  when "two body attract  from distant"

Comment: Is your question about colliding particles, or is it about two objects attracting each other from a distance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **So If I am stationary, the moving observer may say that my measurement is wrong that means Newtons third law is violated? Is it right?**

No that isn't right.

Each observer is in an inertial reference frame and each observer will independently see that Newton's third law applies.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, third law won't apply *solely to particles* in Special Relativity because you need to include the field into conservation of total momentum.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no violation. Both of the observers are in inertial reference frames, and Newton's Laws of Motion hold in inertial reference frames. The only problem would be with *non-inertial * reference frames, but there is no problem now. The difference in time would be possible, especially if the observer and object are travelling in opposite directions.